# Add click count inside an object inside an array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to count the number of clicks triggered by a user on each image. The click count is stored in an object, inside an array. How can I do this?

```
var clicks = 0;
var gatas = [];

gatas[0]= {img : "img/ml.jpg", clicks : 0};
gatas[1]= {img : "img/ma.jpg", clicks : 0};

for (var i = 0; i < gatas.length; i++) {

var elemImg = document.createElement("img");
elemImg.src = gatas[i].img;

var elemClick = document.createElement("h3");

//ADD +1 every time the user clicks an image, storing the count in the 
//object

elemClick.textContent = gatas[i].clicks;

document.body.appendChild(elemClick;
document.body.appendChild(elemPic);

};
```

Comment: Very well. And what’s your question?

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Explain more your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to bind a `click` event handler for every image.

Also, don't forget to use `let` keyword in order to declares a block scope local variable.

Variables declared by `let` have as their scope the block in which they are defined, as well as in any contained **sub-blocks.** In this way, `let` works very much like `var`. The main difference is that the scope of a **var** variable is the entire enclosing function.

This is a problem found usually in [closures.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

```js
var clicks = 0;
var gatas = [];

gatas[0]= {img : "img/ml.jpg", clicks : 0};
gatas[1]= {img : "img/ma.jpg", clicks : 0};
let elemImg=[];
let elemClick=[];
for (let i = 0; i < gatas.length; i++) {
    elemImg[i] = document.createElement("img");
    elemImg[i].src = gatas[i].img;
    elemClick[i] = document.createElement("h3");
    elemClick[i].textContent = gatas[i].clicks;
    elemImg[i].onclick=function(){
      gatas[i].clicks++;
      elemClick[i].textContent = gatas[i].clicks;
    };
    document.body.appendChild(elemClick[i]);
    document.body.appendChild(elemImg[i]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using onClick() for an image tag? 
Insert img tag inside anchor tag and try handling the click with a JavaScript function call.